# How to make `/system` dir files readable using `sepolicy-inject` tool?

Tags: selinux

In enforcing SELinux state, Android `/system` files become unavailable to read in explorer. How to make `/system` dir files readable using `sepolicy-inject` tool?

Also, need `sepolicy-inject` command for setting read-write permission to a single file in the `/system` dir.

Comment: For those who are not familiar with `sepolicy-inject`, is it this tool: https://github.com/phhusson/sepolicy-inject?

Comment: Yes,https://github.com/xmikos/setools-android